# bash/sed/awk/etc remove every other newline

Tags: bash, sed, awk

a bash commands outputs this:

```
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T3:L14
Group State: active
Runtime Name: vmhba3:C0:T0:L14
Group State: active unoptimized
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T1:L14
Group State: active unoptimized
Runtime Name: vmhba3:C0:T3:L14
Group State: active
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T2:L14
Group State: active
```

I'd like to pipe it to something to make it look like this:

```
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T1:L14 Group State: active 
Runtime Name: vmhba3:C0:T3:L14 Group State: active unoptimized
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T2:L14 Group State: active
[...]
```

i.e. remove every other newline

I tried `... |tr "\nGroup" " "` but it removed all newlines and ate up some other letters as well. thanks

Comment: `tr` is entirely character based: you asked tr to remove newlines and all 'G', 'r', 'o', 'u', and 'p'.

Comment: Are you looking for every other (single) newline at the end of a line, or multiple newlines like `\n\n`, or both?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

can't test right now, but

```
... | paste - -
```

should do it

Comment: +1 - works and is elegant. (It puts a tab between the lines - `paste -d ' ' - -` will add a space instead if required)

Comment: Could you please explain how does the command work? Why are there two `-`? Thanks

Comment: `paste` is used to concatenate corresponding lines from files: `paste file1 file2 file3 ...`. If one of the "file" arguments is "-", then lines are read from standard input. If there are 2 "-" arguments, then paste takes 2 lines from stdin. And so on.  See [the man page](http://man.cx/paste).

Answer (score 12):

One possibility is:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?" ":"\n"'
```

If the line number is evenly divisible by 2, end with a new line, otherwise, end with a space.

(Tested on: CentOS 6, GNU Awk 3.1.7)

Using sed (see [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251999/sed-how-can-i-replace-a-newline-n)):

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\nGroup/ Group/g'
```

Further reading:

- [Removing new line characters](http://linux.dsplabs.com.au/rmnl-remove-new-line-characters-tr-awk-perl-sed-c-cpp-bash-python-xargs-ghc-ghci-haskell-sam-ssam-p65/)

Comment: The second link to linux.dsplabs.com.au is broken

Answer (score 9):

If you want to use `sed`, there's no reason to read the whole file into memory. You can merge every other line like this:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ /' inputfile
```

Use any character you'd like instead of the space.

Here's another way using awk:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0; if (getline) print " " $0; else printf "\n"}' inputfile
```

The `if/else` handles the case where there is an odd number of lines in the file. Without it, the odd last line gets printed twice. Otherwise, for comparison, you could do:

```
awk '{printf "%s", $0; getline; print " " $0}'
```

Comment: A late comment: 1) always use a format specifier for printf in case the string has percent signs, 2) to avoid the duplicated last line, set $0 to "" -- `awk '{printf "%s", $0; $0=""; getline; print " " $0}'`

Answer (score 4):

The most idiomatic way to do it in `awk` is as follows:

```
awk 'ORS=NR%2?FS:RS' file
```

It outputs:

```
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T3:L14 Group State: active
Runtime Name: vmhba3:C0:T0:L14 Group State: active unoptimized
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T1:L14 Group State: active unoptimized
Runtime Name: vmhba3:C0:T3:L14 Group State: active
Runtime Name: vmhba2:C0:T2:L14 Group State: active
```

To explain it we need to define each one of the built-in variables:

- `RS` record separator. Defaults to `\n` (new line).
- `ORS` output record separator. Defaults to `\n` (new line).
- `FS` field separator. Defaults to  (space).
- `NR` number of record.

As the default record separator is the new line, a record is, as default, a line.

`NR%2` is the modulus of `NR/2`, so that it will be either `0` or `1`. `0` for even lines and `1` for odd lines.

`var=condition?condition_if_true:condition_if_false` is the ternary operator.

All together, saying `ORS=NR%2?FS:RS` we are defining the output record separator:

- if the number of record is on the form `2k + 1`, that is, on even lines, then the output record separators is set to `FS`, that is, a space.
- if the number of record is on the form `2k`, that is, on odd lines, then the output record separators is set to `RS`, that is, a new line.

This way, odd lines end with a space, that is then joined with the next line. After that line, a new line is printed.

More info in [Idiomatic awk](http://backreference.org/2010/02/10/idiomatic-awk/).

Comment: This also cunningly relies on the fact that the expression also results in either `FS` or `RS`, which are (evidently) both truthy.  If the expression returned something falsy (e.g. `(ORS=...)&&0`, nothing would print.

Answer (score 3):

This works for me on Linux:

```
... | tr "\\n" " "
```

This replaces an empty space for a newline character; you **must** escape the newline character for things to work correctly.

Comment: This removes every newline, not every *other* newline.

Answer (score 2):

In bash:

```
... | while read l1; do read l2; echo "$l1 $l2"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

If Perl is an option:

`perl -pe 's/\n/ / if $. % 2 == 1' file`

`s/\n/ /` replaces newline with space
`$.` is the line number

Answer (score -2):

How about using `grep` ?

```
.. | grep -v '^Group State'
```

Comment: That eliminates the alternate lines. The OP wants them appended.

Comment: Yeah, after re-reading the question I just realized that :)